# Error building/running in simulator on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build, simulator

Using Xcode 6.3.2, I can create a new (blank) project and run it in simulator and it works fine. However when trying to build/run my actual project I get:

> Apple Mach-O linker error
>  clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/usr/lib/CarrierBundleUtilities.dylib'
>   clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o'

I'm new to Xcode, and was able to get past the previous problems I had so far, but now I'm stuck here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dDtJ44h7

Comment: CarrierBundleUtilities.dylib and gcrt1.o are not at that path. Have you added these to your project?

Comment: they are in my project under Frameworks, mr beeblebrox =]

Comment: i removed the references to them, and now im getting an error finding /zbarsdk although it is there

Comment: its saying dir not found for option -L/DWallet/ZBarSDK, although it is clearly in the project

Comment: Make sure in build phases to actually copy needed files. It is not sufficient to have them added in project tree. :) mr beeblebrox :))))))

Comment: in build phases i have zbarsdk in link binary with libraries and copy bundle resources. still getting 'directory not found for option '-L/DWallet/ZBarSDK' although the folder is there in the project and in build phases

Comment: check library search paths, clean project, then rebuild.